# How would you manage stake holder's expectations

Tags: interviewing

From a project menager point of view, there some tips that i can use, but this question actually is in a kind of "before interview lets know you better form".
The tips i mentioned are be like;

1. Identify who the stakeholders are. know the people you will answer
2. Identify the stakeholder’s preferred method of communication.
3. Keep stakeholders engaged throughout the process with timely updates
4. Accurately map expectations.
5. Classify the level of communication for each stakeholder
6. Identify which stakeholders will be advocates and which will be road blockers
7. Engage the stakeholders in decision making
8. Keep the stakeholders in loop, give them updates.

So, i think these tips are not that formal to use in an interview.

My question is how do you manage stake holder's expectations from a general view not only a project manager view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This  question could be more worded more clearly, but if you are asking for interviewing tips I think this answer is not good. It sounds like it was memorized from a book, not like it came from personal experience. You want to be able to connect answers to concrete examples from your work experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always found expectation management to be a highly personalized approach that includes the following:

- Personality and personal biases and leanings of the individual(s)
- Project/Contract/Product goals
- Dynamics of the team involved
- Cost/Price/Bottom line and scheduling needs/demands

As this is usually unique to those criteria, without knowing the specifics it's very hard to answer a question related to "how to" manage expectations.  Generically I would gather all the info and then based on that pick a landing point of the desired expectation(s) and then work backwards to match up all the areas to that end goal.  Please add alot more specifics if you are looking for an exact answer instead of generic approach to expectation management.

P.S. You also don't even mention the industry you are talking about which adds a exponential layer of varied approaches that is impossible to answer without specificity.